# Can I include a custom XML file in my application for default content?

Tags: objective-c, xml, file, installation

I want to load content into my application from a web server, but if the internet is not available, I would like the user to have access to either default or old, downloaded content.  It will be XML formatted.  I know how to download XML from the web server into my app and I can store the XML-as-string and reload.  But, how do I "ship" the product with a default XML data file?  I tried to create a new resource with add-to-project, but I cannot find the file in my application's directory.

Is this possible?

Ok, I am back on this task.  I have my XML properly download from my webserver with a URL pointing to the server's file, however, when I detect the network is 'unreachable' I simply point the URL to my application's local XML and I get the following error.  I cannot find detail description, but I think it is saying that the URL is pointing to an inaccessible location.  Am I storing this resource in the wrong location?  I think I want it in the HomeDirectory / Library??

**Debug output**

```
loadMyXml: /var/mobile/Applications/950569B0-6113-48FC-A184-4F1B67A0510F/MyApp.app/SampleHtml.xml
```

2009-10-14 22:08:17.257 MyApp[288:207] Wah!  It didn't work.
Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=5 "Operation could not be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 5.)"
2009-10-14 22:08:17.270 MyApp[288:207] Operation could not be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 5.)

Comment: That means it's having issues parsing your file.  Also, this should be a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally!  Just include it into your project and make sure it's included in the "Copy Bundle Resources" phase.  Then it will be copied into `./YourApp.app/Contents/Resources/`.  This will work on both Mac and iPhone.

You can easily retrieve it by doing something like this (assuming your file is named "MyXMLFile.plist"):

```
NSString * pathToMyXMLFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyXMLFile" ofType:@"plist"];
```

Comment: Fantastic.  That worked!  I added the following logging and the result  is the file attributes showed the correct filesize of 210 bytes.  Now I can write my access code.  I owe you one ...

 NSString * pathToMyXMLFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SampleHtml" ofType:@"xml"];
 NSError *errorFile = [[NSError alloc] init];
 NSDictionary *attrs;
 attrs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:pathToMyXMLFile error: &errorFile];
 NSLog(@"%@\n:\n%@", pathToMyXMLFile, attrs );